# Excel: Conditional Format specific cells that match rule

Tags: excel

Need help with Conditional formatting Rule

In the example below, I only want to highlight the specific cell that passes the rule - E1 > 100% So, only E3 needs to be highlighted in Red. With the current rule, it is highlighting every cell from E4 thru E13. I only want E3 to highlight because E3 passed the criteria. And similarly for other matching E cells.

[image]
[image]

I have modified the formula per "UrDearBoy" and this is how it looks now and it works!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend rule to ignore text values so change your formula to:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(E1),E1>100%)
```

---

*FYI - Conditional formatting can be processor heavy so I would consider limiting the `Applies To` range to the relevant range rather running this check on all ~1MIL rows*

[image]

Comment: Where your original formula is applied that just says 'E1 > 100%`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set up a rule with these properties by using "Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Greater Than" and then set the value to 1 as in the below screenshots.

[image: Rule Description]

[image: Rules Manager Example]

Comment: No cookie, mgrollins.  see updated question w/ screen grab.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a simple formula based solution, you can use:

```
=N(E1)>100%
```

The `N()` function converts text to 0 and numbers to their numerical value.